# Mongodb move item in collection

Tags: mongodb

Is there a simple way to move one item in mongodb collection to another position.

Example if I have:

```js
[ { _id:"xxxxxx", name: "itemOne" }, 
{ _id:"xxxxxx", name: "itemTwo" }, 
{ _id:"xxxxxx", name: "itemThree" } ]
```

I want to move itemOne to index 2. Result would be:

```js
[ { _id:"xxxxxx", name: "itemTwo" }, 
{ _id:"xxxxxx", name: "itemThree" }, 
{ _id:"xxxxxx", name: "itemOne" } ]
```

Comment: can you share the exact structure of your document, and please add what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using MongoDB, the order documents are returned is undefined unless you specify a sort stage.

If you need documents returned in an order other than increasing or decreasing, add an `order` field specifying the ordering you want, and sort on that field.